# react : Textarea.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase') at onUpClick (Textarea.js:16:1)

Tags: reactjs

i was trying to make a textbox that converts the text into upper case and i am facing errors in the console like this: "Textarea.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase')     at onUpClick (Textarea.js:16:1)"
can someone please tell me wheere did i go wrong!

[please help me out guys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6ipV.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change onClick in your button to `<button onClick={e => onUpClick()} ...` becouse `<button onClick={onUpClick} ..>` triggers  once the component mount and then it will call toUpperCase() where the text is undefined
Or you could just in your useState do this `useState("")` set an initial value to it insted of undefined